# How can I add the array key data item in google maps marker infowindow for an array of markers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building a js function to init a google map and add an array fo markers to a map with the individual locations set for them from the array.

The markers get added okay and they position fine but I am struggling to obtain a certain part of the data array and add each piece of info from that array into each markers pop up.

Here is the code I am using below.

Basically what happens is that I click the marker it opens the pop up but it only shows the last data item in the array.

JS:

```
initMap: function() {

            // Lets detect mobile maps here
            function detectBrowser() {
              var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
              var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

              if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ) {
                mapdiv.style.width = '100%';
                mapdiv.style.height = '100%';
              } else {
                mapdiv.style.width = '100%';
                mapdiv.style.height = '700px';
              }
            }


            // Do rest here


            var cities = {

               'Groningen':  [ 'name 1', 53.216723950863425, 6.560211181640625, 7],
               'San Francisco': [  'name 2', 34.01131647557699, -118.25599389648437, 5],
               'New York City': [  'name 3', 40.7143528, -74.0059731, 3]

             };

            var markers = [];
            var iterator = 0;



            detectBrowser();

            var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5254559, -0.0777409);
            var mapOptions = { zoom: 10,scrollwheel: false,center: mapCenter,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
            var image = 'http://shiftms2:8888/wp-content/themes/shiftms/images/mobile/mobile_logo.png';


            function setMarkers(map, cities) {

                  for (var key in cities) {

                     console.log(cities[key][0]);

                      var data = cities[key];
                      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: new google.maps.LatLng (data[1], data[2]),
                          map: map,
                          icon: image,
                          zIndex: data[3]

                      });
                      var infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
                        content: '<div class="bubble"><div alt="' + cities[key][0] + '" class="left-col2 text"><h4>' + cities[key][0] + '</h4><p class="size">' + cities[key][0] + '</p></div></div>',
                        boxClass: 'info-box',
                        alignBottom: true,
                        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-150, -40),
                        maxWidth: 370,
                        padding: 0,
                        closeBoxMargin: '0px',
                        borderColor: '#ffffff',
                        borderRadius: '0',
                        minWidth: 535,
                        disableAutoPan: false,
                        hideCloseButton: false,
                        backgroundClassName: 'phoney'
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () { 
                        infoBubble.open(map, this);
                    });   

                  }



              }

            setMarkers(map, cities);

        }
```

Any help would be great on this, I think its not far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the listeners are referring to the last infoBubble created which in this instance is `New York City` you have to create the infoBubble `onclick` and then destroy on exit or make 1 which gets re-populated `onclick` and hidden on exit.

UPDATE 1
E.g.

Javascript:

```
for (var key in cities) {
    var city = cities[key];
    city.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[1], data[2]),
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        zIndex: city[3]

    });

    ....

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
        showInfoBubble(city);
    });.....
}


// somewhere else 
function showInfoBubble(city) {
    var infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
        content: '<div class="bubble"><div alt="' + city[0] + '" class="left-col2 text"><h4>' + city[0] + '</h4><p class="size">' + city[0] + '</p></div></div>',
        boxClass: 'info-box',
        alignBottom: true,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-150, -40),
        maxWidth: 370,
        padding: 0,
        closeBoxMargin: '0px',
        borderColor: '#ffffff',
        borderRadius: '0',
        minWidth: 535,
        disableAutoPan: false,
        hideCloseButton: false,
        backgroundClassName: 'phoney'
    });

    // Now open the infoBubble at the marker
    infoBubble.open(map, city.marker);
}
```

Comment: so shall that be created outside the for loop you reckon?

Comment: Cheers Rob will have a look now

Comment: @Mdunbavan Hi Chap, have a look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U9W4R/ using jQuery.each solved a scope issue encountered in using the `for` loop